# Nativescript footbar with angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am very new to Nativescript UI. How can I place footer in Nativescript with angular2.

I am designing page with tabs. where i need to show list view and footer in one tab. List view is working perfect as like in below image. My concern is to design footer and fab button. I don't have much experience on changes.

Code follows :

```
<TabView [selectedIndex]="tabindex" selectedColor="#FF0000">
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Appertiser'}" >
    <Label text="Hello, I am Appertiser" marginTop="20" fontSize="20" horizontalAlignment="center" textAlignment="center"></Label>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Noodles'}" >
    <ListView [items]="products">
        <template let-item="item">
            <GridLayout  rows="auto" columns="auto,*" class="list-wrapper">
                <Image  row="0" col="0" [src]="item.productImage" horizontalAlignment="left"></Image>
                <StackLayout row="0" col="1" orientation="vertical" horizontalAlignment="left" class="productDetail">
                    <Label [text]='item.productName' horizontalAlignment="left" class="productHeading"></Label>
                    <Label [text]='item.productShortDescription'  horizontalAlignment="left" class="productDescription"></Label>
                    <Label [text]='item.productTags'  horizontalAlignment="left" class="productTags"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <Image row="0" col="2" [src]="item.iconImage" width="20px" height="20px" horizontalAlignment="right"  verticalAlignment="top" marginRight="10"></Image>
                <GridLayout row="0" col="3" orientation="vertical" verticalAlignment="bottom">
                    <Label [text]='item.productPrice' class="productPrice" textColor="red" horizontalAlignment="right" class="productPrice"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </template>

    </ListView>

    <FAB (tap)="toggleNav('Home')" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" class="fab-button"></FAB>


</StackLayout>
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Seafood'}">
    <Label text="Hello, I am Seafood" marginTop="20" fontSize="20"  textAlignment="left"></Label>

    <GridLayout row="1" column="0" rows="auto" columns="50,*,50" verticalAlignment="bottom" backgroundColor="lightgray" cssClass="footer">
        <Label text="My cat loves the camera" textWrap="true" col="1" colSpan="2" minHeight="50" fontSize="20" margin="3"></Label>
        <Label text="John Smith" col="1" row="1" fontSize="14" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="bottom" margin="3"></Label>
        <Label text="comments: 26" col="2" row="1" color="#10C2B0" fontSize="14" verticalAlignment="bottom" margin="3"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout cssClass="footer" row="1" column="0" rows="auto" columns="50,*,50">
        <Image src="{{flag}}" cssClass="flagimage" col="0" row="0"></Image>
        <Label text="{{lang}}" tap="{{goDefault}}" col="1" row="0" textAlignment="left"></Label>
        <Image src="~/res/icons/white/ellipsis_white.png" cssClass="iconwhitesmall" tap="{{goOther}}" row="0" col="2"></Image>
    </GridLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get familiar with ***NativeScript + Angular-2***  I wo8uld recommend to check out [this sample app](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng) where a number of basic scenarios are shown.

As for your question - What exactly do you mean by "footer" !? A semantic footer [layout](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/layouts) for main page or menu or maybe a [footer for list-view controller](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/listview/customizing-listview)? The answer depends on your specific needs so please share a code of what you have done so far and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Nick, I need to design footer for list-view where i have to place buttons and text. I am designing UI in html based not in xml based